# SQLAlchemy : FOR XML PATH equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

How do I put a column containing multiple rows in a XML tag?

Here is my sample mssql code snippet,

```
(SELECT DESCRIPTION 
 FROM WEV_STY PS WITH(NOLOCK) 
 JOIN MOEE_POV_STY MPS 
 WITH(NOLOCK) ON PS.STY_CD = MPS.PRV_STY_CD 
 FOR XML PATH('')) PPB_SDD
```

What is sqlalchemy equivalent for the above query? 
How to translate **FOR XML PATH(' ')** to sqlalchemy?

Comment: You can use `literal_column` for this use case. It allows you put an **arbitrary** string as a column expression (**literally**). Example: `session.query(table.idn, literal_column("(select 1) as test").all`. As long as the `literal_column` is a **valid** SQL column expression, it works fine. Remember, it will work for a specific DB only!

Answer (score 1):

## SQL SERVER < 2017 version

I have achieved string concatination without using 'FOR XML PATH' by writing a python function to do the string concatination on the results obtained by the SQLAlchemy query without 'FOR XML PATH' on sql server version lesser than 2017.

Get the results of the below query:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION, PS.STY_CD AS ID 
 FROM WEV_STY PS WITH(NOLOCK) 
 JOIN MOEE_POV_STY MPS 
 WITH(NOLOCK) ON PS.STY_CD = MPS.PRV_STY_CD
```

Lets say,

```
query_result = [{'DESCRIPTION': 'ABC', 'ID':1},  {'DESCRIPTION': 'DEF', 'ID': 2} {'DESCRIPTION': 'XYZ'. 'ID':1}]
```

result = string_concatination(query_result) # Implement string_concatination functionality based on same 'ID'

```
result = [{'DESCRIPTION': 'ABC, XYZ', 'ID': 1}, {'DESCRIPTION': 'DEF', 'ID': 2 }]
```

Note: Since we were getting lesser number of rows from the db table, we used this as a present solution.

## SQL SERVER version >= 2017

SQL server has built in string concatination functionality 'STRING_AGG() WITHIN GROUP()' and can be used with SQLAlchemy 'func' method.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw SQL query in SQLALCHEMY. Based on [SQLALCHEMY doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures) and [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server), Try something like:

```
# pymssql
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')
raw_con = engine.raw_connection()

try:
    cursor = raw_con.cursor()

    # add your proper SQL code here
    cursor.execute('(SELECT DESCRIPTION 
                     FROM WEV_STY PS WITH(NOLOCK) 
                     JOIN MOEE_POV_STY MPS 
                     WITH(NOLOCK) ON PS.STY_CD = MPS.PRV_STY_CD 
                     FOR XML PATH('')) PPB_SDD;')

    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
finally:
    raw_con.close()
```

Comment: Is there not a way of executing this query using raw SQLAlchemy as opposed to executing the raw SQL query using a SQLAlchemy engine?